# REACT: Change text displayed on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On the homepage, I want users to hover over a span and when they do the content of the span changes and the background changes too.

I've created an array to store the data, the text changing and the background image. I'm going to concat the src files for the background.

I found this code snippet and have adapted it. I'm having an issue with the innerHTML as I'm not using jQuery. I don't know what to do in jsx.

The hover action is working, I did a console log but it's breaking at the innerHTML part.

The array is 2 component levels up.

```
//-Home.js  
//--Hero.js  
//---HeroImageItems.js (this is where the code below resides)  

export class HeroImageItems extends Component {
  loopHeroTitle = () => {
    let list = this.props.heroImage.title;
    titleSequence(0);

    function titleSequence(i) {
      if (list.length > i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("hero-image-title").innerHTML = list[i];
          titleSequence(++i);
        }, 1000);
      } else if (list.length == i) {
        titleSequence(0);
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hero-image-bg">
        <p
          className="hero-image-title"
          id="hero-title-span"
          onMouseOver={this.loopHeroTitle}
          style={this.getActiveText()}
        >
          {this.props.heroImage.title}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HeroImageItems.propTypes = {
  heroImages: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default HeroImageItems;
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context about what you're trying to do? What is `titleSequence`?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong id. 
 document.getElementById("hero-image-title").innerHTML = list[i];
 is where you are setting the innerHTML.

This p tag has an id of "hero-title-span"

Put the correct id in and you should be good to go!

Comment: This cleared the error- omds thanks, how could I miss that lool! Right now it's looping through the letters in the selected array item. I want it to loop through the different items. Should I add the array code to the question